# Pandas df, convert column of pd.Timedelta to days

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timedelta

I have a pandas dataframe where one of the columns contains pandas.Timedelta data. I'd like to convert this to get from this a column with the days of the timedeltas.
I tried to get this column and get the days with .dt but it failed.
`df.time_deltas.df.days`

please, help )`:

Comment: can you provide the full error traceback?

Comment: I close question because typo.

Comment: `get the days with .dt but it failed. df.time_deltas.df.days`

Comment: I seconded @jezrael's close vote.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is `df.time_deltas.dt.days` (d**t**, not d**f**):

example:

```
from pandas import Timedelta
df = pd.DataFrame({'time_delta': [Timedelta('1 days 02:00:00'),
                                  Timedelta('0 days 02:00:00'),
                                  Timedelta('5 days 00:00:00')]})

df.time_delta.dt.days
```

output:

```
0    1
1    0
2    5
Name: time_delta, dtype: int64
```